# Nextjs shallow routing for tabs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Have a tabs component which work perfectly with the router.query state

```
useEffect(() => {
        let found = false;

        if (currentTab !== 'leads') {
            router.push(`${id}?tab=${currentTab}`, undefined, {
                shallow: true,
            });
        }
    }, [currentTab]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.tab !== currentTab) {
            setCurrentTab(router.query.tab);
        }
    }, [router.query.tab]);
```

The problem arises when the rendered  tab component push its own query state.

```
useEffect(() => {
        router.push(`?${queryString.stringify({tab:"y")}`, undefined, {
            shallow: true,
        });


    }, [state]);
```

the below useEffect router.push tab doesnt affect the second useEffect. so if i move tab from x to y. the url bar tab stucks to x but the component works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a reproduction in code sandbox? I use query params in tabs, but different approach.

I use this custom hook (with MUI tabs). It returns a tab `value` and `onChange` which I pass to tabs.

```
export const useTabsValue = (): [TabsValue, TabsOnChange] => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const currentTab = router.query[QUERY_PARAM__PROFILE_TAB] ?? 0;

  return [
    Number(currentTab),
    (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
      if (newValue === 0) {
        router.push('/profile');
        return;
      }

      router.push(`/profile?${QUERY_PARAM__PROFILE_TAB}=${newValue}`);
    },
  ];
};
```

Usage

```
const [value, onChange] = useTabsValue();
```

This would require you to change how your tabs work. But most of the tabs should get `onChange` handler (maybe check [radix-ui](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/tabs) for accessible tabs)

You can also check out [next-query-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-query-params) lib that may help you out, for controlling the query params state.

Hope something helps you from this.
Best,
Hypercloud